# Syntax Error: 'await' outside async function in Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I started coding a command in my discord bot which enables users to interact with the bot using messages. However, when I run my program, I run into this error:

`'await' outside async function`

I've checked out other posts which said indentation would solve the problem, but I am using a while loop in my code.

```
@client.command()
async def Bot (ctx):
  def Bot1():
    while True:
      Initiate = input ("Type in anything to start, type 'Quit' to end ")
      if Initiate == 'Hello':
        await ctx.send ("Hello there!")
      elif Initiate == 'Quit':
        break
        
      else:
        Responses = ['How are you doing today', 'What do you want to talk about', 'The bot is at your service']
        Response = random.choose(Responses)
        await ctx.send (Response)
  await ctx.send (Bot1())
```

Comment: `Bot1` isn't async but you have `await`s within it.

Answer (score 2):

your Bot1 function

```py
  def Bot1():
```

is wrong.

if you are using `await` inside the function, in your case you are using, you must have:

```py
async def Bot1():
```

#### edit after problem number 2:

i think your problem is this line

```py
 await ctx.send (Bot1())
```

this must be converted to

```py
 await ctx.send (Bot1)
```

or

```py
 await ctx.send (await Bot1())
```

Comment: I tried what you did, and the it sends me this message:  RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'bot.<locals>.Bot1' was never awaited. Any idea what it means?

Comment: check the question. i've made some edits

Comment: seems to work, but it prints it on the terminal instead of the channel :(

Comment: i dont know, man, its related to discord API. but one thing is sure. `you cant have await in non-async func`

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
def Bot():
   #Code ...
   return Response
```

Instead of

```
await ctx.send (Response)
```

since you are already sending it outside the function.

You can also remove the sending code outside, and make the function a coroutine which can be done with

```
async def Bot():
  #your code
```